# Director sum, isometric

Tags: functional-analysis

let $ E $ be a normed space that can be represented as a direct sum of two vector subspaces: $ E = F + G $. Show that $\frac{ E}{ F}$ is isometric with $ G $
Using the quotient norm since $ F $ is a closed subspace I want to build the bijective mapping between the quotient space and$ G$.
One idea is to take an ismorphism theorem that is an isometry but I have not gotten far.
The other is to directly construct the function but I don't see how to proceed from the definition of quotient norm, maybe it is some extension.
Will you have any comments or suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$(1).\ $ the projection $\pi:E\oplus F\to E$ is linear and has kernel equal to $F$, so the first isomorphism theorem applies to say.....

$(2).\ \pi $  maps the unit ball $B^{E\oplus F}_1(0)$ onto the unit ball $B^{E}_1(0)$, so...

Comment: By $E\otimes F$ perhaps do you mean $E=F\oplus G$?

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Thank you.